# measure of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to calculate the measure of following intervals:
$$ \mu^*((a,b)), \mu^*((a,b)], \mu^*([a,b]) 
$$
Therefore I consider $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $ \mu : F^1  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \  \mu(A) = \sum_{i=1}^m g(b_i) -g(a_i) $ and $ A=\bigcup_{i=1}^m (a_i,b_i]$. The intervals are disjoint.
g is a left-continous and monotonically increasing function. $\mu , \mu^*$ are measures.

Now I can apply Carathéodory's theorem on $\mu$ to get $\mu^*$, which is defined on   $B(\mathbb{R}) := \sigma(F^1)$
$$ \mu^*(A)= \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu\left((a_i,b_i]\right) : A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^m (a_i,b_i] \right\}
$$

Can anybody help me calculating $$ \mu^*((a,b)), \mu^*((a,b)], \mu^*([a,b])?
$$

Comment: can you explain the notations used in your question? What tare $\mu$ and $\mu*$? WHy are you considering $g$ and what is $f$?

Comment: Sorry I will edit that

Comment: If you are attempting to typeset $\mu^*$, use `\mu^*`.

Comment: Thanks for your advise:)

Comment: I mixed up f and g. f is wrong. Can you understand everything now?

Comment: Why don't you try using your definition of $\mu^*$? Let $A = (a,b)$. What do you get?

Comment: But how? I don' get that. Can show, how you would do this?

Comment: Where there is an $A$, write $(a, b)$. You should get $(a, b) \subset \ldots$. That should tell you how to choose your intervals $(a_i, b_i)$.